# Unable to make azure continuous integration build pipeline due to Execution failed for task ':react-native-image-picker:testDebugUnitTest'

Tags: react-native, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am using   "react-native": "0.62.2"  and my gradle settings look like,

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 23
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
glideVersion = "4.9.0"
kotlin_version = "1.3.50"
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

I have issues while building the project on azure CI pipeline

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-image-picker:testDebugUnitTest'.

> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I found some similar issues, you can refer to them: [Issue](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1121) ,[Issue](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/972) , [Issue](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1142) . It looks like your question is related to [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues).

Comment: Thank you @jeff , You helped me

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If yes, can you post your solution and mark it? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers. Thank you.

Comment: yes and I will send the answer @WalterQian-MSFT please find the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that by adding first

```
   lintOptions {
                    abortOnError false
                    disable 'InvalidPackage'
                    checkReleaseBuilds false
                }
```

then

```
roject.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.js",
]
```